# AWS Api gateway write to S3 with timestamp as filename

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to create an endpoint on Api Gateway that writes on AWS s3 bucket using a filename like `data/$timestamp` where timestamp is the `$context.requestTimeEpoch` variable that should be available in each request

My api gateway request integration is this

```
{
    "type": "AWS",
    "httpMethod": "PUT",
    "uri": "arn:aws:apigateway:eu-west-1:bucketname.s3:path/data/{reqTimestamp}",
    "credentials": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/ApiGatewayWriteToDemoS3Bucket",
    "requestParameters": {
        "integration.request.path.reqTimestamp": "context.requestTime"
    },
    "passthroughBehavior": "WHEN_NO_MATCH",
    "timeoutInMillis": 29000,
    "cacheNamespace": "5f92eajcg9",
    "cacheKeyParameters": [],
    "integrationResponses": {
        "200": {
            "statusCode": "200",
            "responseParameters": {
                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'"
            },
            "responseTemplates": {
                "application/json": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However I get this error

`Execution failed due to configuration error: Illegal character in path at index 49: https://bucketname.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/data/{reqTimestamp}`

it worked only once, then I had an S3 authentication error but that's another story

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a value in the URL Path Parameter configuration of the Integration Request in your API Gateway resource method, setting the name to `reqTimestamp`, and value to `method.request.path.reqTimestamp`.

This will map the value received by API Gateway in the URL to the path override parameter you defined.